# What is the English translation of the French dialogue in "Croissant de Triomphe"?

Tags: translation, mickey-mouse-tv

"[Croissant de Triomphe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCaxXQdkfPk)," one of the episodes of the 2013 cartoon series *[Mickey Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mickey_Mouse_%28TV_series%29)*, contains all French dialogue.

What is the English translation of the episode's dialogue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going into the details of each line of the dialogue, here's a short summary :

- Minnie's taking orders, all the clients ask for a croissant and a coffee.
- Minnie realizes she's out of croissants, she asks Mickey to go and get some.
- Mickey takes his scooter and goes on his quest for the croissants.
- Clients ask where the croissants are, Minnie tries to offer an omelette, then a soufflé, but they refuse and keep asking for the croissants.
- When Mickey comes back with the croissants, he falls and tosses them into the air. The children on the carousel tell Mickey they've caught them.
- Mickey fetches the croissants with his baguette spear and tells the clients "Attention everybody, here come the croissants", then throws them into the plates.